# how can i make the following query more efficient in lookup with many conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, database-design

First of all i need to have a functionality of pagination by limiting the result in the following query lookup with couple where conditions.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    a.uid, b.NAME
FROM
    `profiles` AS a FORCE INDEX(profiles_country_city_gender_index)
JOIN `users` AS b
ON b.id = a.uid
AND a.country = 'INDONESIA'
AND a.gender = 0
JOIN (
    SELECT
        a.uid
    FROM
       profile_details AS a
    JOIN profile_details AS kids ON kids.uid = a.uid
    AND kids.kids_pref = 1
    JOIN profile_details AS current ON current.uid = a.uid
    AND current.current_relationship = 1
    JOIN profile_details AS smoking ON smoking.uid = a.uid
    AND smoking.smoking_pref = 1
    ) AS e ON e.uid = a.uid
AND ( TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, a.birth_date, NOW()) BETWEEN 25 AND 35 )
LIMIT 33;
```

All tables here is one on one relation with table Users which are

- Profiles
- Profile_details

Using id column as Primary key in Users, and uid in the other tables as Foreign key.
At the start, i do not have problem with the above query/design until the tables grows till 300K rows in it, the query running takes `OK, Time: 0.726000s` to fetch the result which is too slow for my opinion.

I tried to count the rows based on the conditions above using count(*) and get some approximate same result, 
i need to have the faster way to get the count of rows from the lookup conditions to make the pagination system works as expected with less waiting time.

As you can see in the query, i am using:

```
FORCE INDEX(profiles_country_city_gender_index)
```

I think it's not helping much caused by the larger rows result from the scope by using:

```
AND a.country = 'INDONESIA' 
AND a.gender = 0
```

Resulting (148801 rows scope limit by country  with gender is equal by 0), if i am pairing with city it's not problem query time is considerable because rows result much smaller but still gonna be a problem when there were larger rows at someday.

To anyone who might ask for the query explanation:

```
Explain SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
        a.uid, 
        b.NAME ...

Results:

| select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys                      | key                                | key_len | ref              | rows   | filtered  | Extra                              |
+-------------+---------+--------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+------------------+--------+-----------+------------------------------------+
| SIMPLE      | a       | ref    | profiles_country_city_gender_index | profiles_country_city_gender_index | 242     | const            | 148801 | 10.00     | Using index condition; Using where |
| SIMPLE      | a       | ref    | profile_details_uid_foreign        | profile_details_uid_foreign        | 3       | restfulapi.a.uid | 1      | 100.00.00 | Using index                        |
| SIMPLE      | kids    | ref    | profile_details_uid_foreign        | profile_details_uid_foreign        | 3       | restfulapi.a.uid | 1      | 10.00     | Using where                        |
| SIMPLE      | current | ref    | profile_details_uid_foreign        | profile_details_uid_foreign        | 3       | restfulapi.a.uid | 1      | 10.00     | Using where                        |
| SIMPLE      | smoking | ref    | profile_details_uid_foreign        | profile_details_uid_foreign        | 3       | restfulapi.a.uid | 1      | 10.00     | Using where                        |
| SIMPLE      | b       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY                            | 3       | restfulapi.a.uid | 1      | 100.00.00 |                                    |
```

As you can see in explain result, no table scan or using temporary or using range, only index condition. 
I imagine if the tables have at least 1 million rows returns by Country scope, just multiply the time with scaling rows by 300K it sucks :(.

Below is the table definition in case it helps to analysing the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE `profile_details` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `intents` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
  `height` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
  `kids_pref` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `drinking_pref` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `living_with` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `current_relationship` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `sexual_pref` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `smoking_pref` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status_online` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `profile_details_uid_foreign` (`uid`),
  KEY `idx_multipart` (`intents`,`body_type`,`kids_pref`,`drinking_pref`,`living_with`,`current_relationship`,`sexual_pref`,`smoking_pref`),
  CONSTRAINT `profile_details_uid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` date NOT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `country` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ID',
  `city` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'Makassar',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `longitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `profiles_uid_foreign` (`uid`),
  KEY `profiles_birth_date_index` (`birth_date`),
  KEY `profiles_latitude_longitude_index` (`latitude`,`longitude`),
  KEY `profiles_country_city_gender_index` (`country`,`city`,`gender`),
  KEY `idx_country_gender_birthdate` (`country`,`gender`,`birth_date`),
  KEY `idx_country_city_gender_birthdate` (`country`,`city`,`gender`,`birth_date`),
  CONSTRAINT `profiles_uid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
)
```

How can I find the solution, do i need to redesign the table  to get the ideal system? perhaps it is the last option.

**EDIT**

I am trying what you suggested earlier, first i added an index in three column:

```
CREATE INDEX profiles_country_gender_birth_date_index on `profiles`(country,gender,birth_date);
```

and i tried to select Count(*) without JOIN with profile_detail:

```
SELECT
    count(*)


FROM
    `profiles` AS a 
    FORCE INDEX ( profiles_country_gender_birth_date_index )
    JOIN `users` AS b ON b.id = a.uid 
and 
a.country = 'INDONESIA' 

    AND a.gender =1 
    AND a.birth_date BETWEEN NOW()- INTERVAL 35 YEAR 
    AND NOW()- INTERVAL 25 YEAR
```

result timing is not stable between 0.7sec to 0.35sec and i don't know why it could be. 
Below is Explain Query Plan in Json Format just in case to help to find out the culprit.

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "114747.38"
    },
    "nested_loop": [
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "a",
          "access_type": "range",
          "possible_keys": [
            "profiles_country_gender_birth_date_index"
          ],
          "key": "profiles_country_gender_birth_date_index",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "country",
            "gender",
            "birth_date"
          ],
          "key_length": "246",
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 94066,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 32961,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "index_condition": "((`restfulapi`.`a`.`gender` = 1) and (`restfulapi`.`a`.`country` = 'INDONESIA') and (`restfulapi`.`a`.`birth_date` between <cache>((now() - interval 35 year)) and <cache>((now() - interval 25 year))))",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "15858.00",
            "eval_cost": "6592.23",
            "prefix_cost": "75194.00",
            "data_read_per_join": "16M"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "uid",
            "birth_date",
            "gender",
            "country"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "b",
          "access_type": "eq_ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "PRIMARY"
          ],
          "key": "PRIMARY",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "id"
          ],
          "key_length": "3",
          "ref": [
            "restfulapi.a.uid"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 32961,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "using_index": true,
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "32961.15",
            "eval_cost": "6592.23",
            "prefix_cost": "114747.38",
            "data_read_per_join": "89M"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "id"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please format that table in columns so we can read it. Please capitalize "I" & the first letter of a sentence. Please break up your thoughts into smaller sentences. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please give a complete [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable code including DDL & initialization code formatted as a table. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. Ask re optimization after you learn & apply those basics.

Comment: ups, sorry. gonna edit the content and follow the convention. thanks to remind me.

Comment: "Using Index Condition" is (often) a full scan.  An alternate name is "ICP" (Index Condition Pushdown), wherein the Engine, instead of the "Handler", checks more of the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INDEX(country, gender, birth_date)  -- in this order
```

and change the use of `birth_date` to be "sargeable":

```
AND  ( TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, a.birth_date, NOW()) BETWEEN 25 AND 35 )
```

to

```
AND a.birth_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 35 YEAR
                     AND NOW() - INTERVAL 25 YEAR
```

So that the optimizer can use `birth_date`.

`LIMIT 33` -- Do you care which 33 rows?  Maybe you need an `ORDER BY`?

Don't do `JOIN ( SELECT ... profile_details ... )` when a plan `JOIN profile_details ...` would work.

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` costs something.  Remove it to see how fast it goes, then decide whether it is worth keeping.

I don't think you need to `JOIN profile_details` more than once, especially since it is 1:1 with `profiles`.

Here's what I mean:

Instead of `JOIN ( SELECT ... )` have just

```
JOIN  profile_details AS d  USING(uid)
```

Then add these to the WHERE clause:

```
AND  d.kids_pref = 1
AND  d.current_relationship = 1
AND  d.smoking_pref = 1
```

**Avoiding filesort**

```
INDEX(country, gender,   -- Tested with '='
      birth_date,        -- Tested as a "range"
      uid)               -- For the ORDER BY -- Useless!
```

When building an index, include columns in this order

1. All columns tested as "column = constant".
2. One Range (such as `BETWEEN`).  If this is the same as the `ORDER BY` then "filesort" is probably avoided.

If there were no "range" in the `WHERE`, then

1. All columns tested as "column = constant".
2. The `ORDER BY` columns -- assuming they are all `DESC` or all `ASC` (or, in MySQL 8.0, match the `INDEX` definition).  This will probably avoid "filesort".

But an index cannot handle both a "range" and a different "order by".  Consider the following.  You have a list of people with last name and first name.  And the query is

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE last_name LIKE 'Ja%'   -- a "range"
    ORDER BY first_name;
```

`INDEX(last_name, first_name)` will help with the `WHERE`, but have the first_names jumbled.  And vice versa.

(That is a simplification, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql for some more details.)

Comment: i've tried to create index in country, gender,birth_date and tried to running the query with persisting SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, seems slow execution time about 1.2 sec, running it again and replace SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with count(*)  and this time execution time is about 0.6-0.4 sec but i can see the order of the rows is changed. About JOIN ( SELECT ... profile_details ... ) it's absolutely not working with regular JOIN, means when i use regular JOIN execution time above 1 sec. LIMIT 33 means the client need to traverse through the pages and only 33 rows per pages at a time.

Comment: If you don't have an `ORDER BY`, the pagination could duplicate or skip items.  Even if you do, it can still fail due to inserts/deletes from other connections.

Comment: @aurakarya - I added a note about the repeated `JOIN`.

Comment: you were right i don't need repeated JOIN, it just slowing the query and i have tried to execute it and gain performance in time by 0.32 which nearly half than the original Query, in the last JOIN Would have till 8 conditions is there a way to improving it much further?

Comment: i added the schema information for both profiles and profile_details in case it helps to analysing.

Comment: @aurakarya - Notice that it used only the `country` part of your index.  My suggested index should make use of all three parts.  Use `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` to get more details.

Comment: @aurakarya - And I elaborated on the `JOIN` simplification.

Comment: I edited the post following your suggestions, result timing it self unstable between 0.7sec to 0.35sec. Anyway thanks for your time to try to help me.

Comment: ORDER By uid always give me filesort how can I avoid filesort? Have tried to add index in these order  country,city,gender,birth_date,uid  but still mysql cannot use uid as index in sorting process. Can you enlighten me how could it happen?

Comment: @aurakarya - I added to my Answer.

Comment: At first when I designed the schema, I think it's easy to playing with indexed, totally wrong application feature is rather complex because have the ability to filter and sorting at the same time and what makes it complex is too many filtering condition country, city(this could become range by specify IN operator), gender, and last birth_date(which really a range). Do you think there is another approach to get the app feature which I wanted for? How about with PARTITION feature?

Comment: @aurakarya - I discuss the 2D feature of partitioning in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint .  However, generally it is "good enough" to build an index that handles the "=" tests, plus one "range".  After that, the filtering for a second range or the sorting for an `ORDER BY` may not be too inefficient.  That is, when you cannot make a perfect index, work on making an index that is good enough. @aurakarya